# Trying to bake texture but it's saying that it's an uninitialized image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texture-baking

I'm trying to bake a principled shader for an animation, but it tells me that I have an uninitialized image. Don't know what to do.

Comment: For me, the case was a buggy image in the second material of the object. I deleted that image. Than the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 8):

In the *Texture Image* node, where it normally says **Single Image**, change it to **Generated**.

Comment: Gonna save it for later use as it worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new blank image with transparency (choose your size, maybe 2K resolution). In the current shader tree include a texture image connected to a diffuse shader.

Your procedural shader network should be mixed with the image node->Diffuse with a Mix shader node. Lastly, that node should connect to *Material Output*.

Your viewport should still be showing your procedural shader only.
Now, go to the **Render Properties**, scroll down to **Bake**, and choose *Diffuse*. Press Bake.

If you make a screen capture of your setup that would help, as well.